# Cycles Material doesn't show correctly on some objects (but it does on others)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm a noob in using Blender.

I'm using a cycles material on a bunch of "wood objects". It works perfectly. Then I create some new objects from some cubes, and the material doesn't show correctly.

I thought I did something wrong (like flipping the normals or some other crazy thing), so I tried to apply the material to a simple cube, without doing anything to it... and it still doesn't work as supposed.

Practically, the color of the material is there, but the textures are not.
The attached image should explain the problem quite clearly: on the desk the material works properly, on the cube at the left it doesn't.

[image: On the desk the material works properly, on the cube at the left it doesn't]

This is the viewport rendering, but the problem persists even on the final rendering.

Anyone can explain the reason of this behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: if colors are there, probably UVs missing.Unwrap cube or use generated UVs and box projection

Comment: @Shubol3D Yes, Unwrap did the trick! Thank you.